# Dynamics 365 CRM Online: Turn off column size cap for audit data

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I read the microsoft documentation mentions that there is a cap of 5kb ~5000 characters recorded in the audit log: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/audit-data-user-activity

> Large attribute values, such as Email.description or Annotation, are
> limited (capped) at 5KB or ~5,000 characters. A capped attribute value
> can be recognized by three dots at the end of the text, for example,
> “lorem ipsum, lorem ip…”.

For security and compliance reasons, the client has insisted that the 5000 character audit limit is not sufficient to meet regulations

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure/force Dynamics CRM 365 online to accept a higher size (e.g. 20,000 characters)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the audit logic but you can create a plugin to store the old value when a specific column is modified, you will need also to create a new table to mimic the audit one with columns large enough to store the old value.